# How do I activate SSL as a 'mutt' user?

Tags: ssl, mutt

My provider says I have to activate SSL in order to (continue to) be able to read my mail.
I use 'mutt', and I haven't been able to find out how to do this (activate SSL). 
The provider was unable to tell me.
Do I have to add something to  .muttrc  ? 
(I have a pop account and use fetchmail.)

G.Heinlein

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question for *reading* mail but I just learned that for sending mail, you can configure mutt to use SSL with smtp**s** in the `smtp_url`, in `~/.muttrc`. Example: set smtp_url = "smtp**s**://myemail@somewhere.com@my.smtp.host.com:465/" assuming the port is 465.

Answer (score 2):

If you use fetchmail to get the mails locally and then read them with mutt you don't need to configure mutt for ssl, but fetchmail. And fetchmail by itself tries to use ssl in the default configuration, e.g. it issues the STLS command after opening a plain connection. If the provider asks you to use pop3s instead of pop3 (e.g. encrypted from start instead of encrypted after the STLS command) you should specify the 'ssl' keyword in your fetchmailrc.

Comment: In the meantime I learnt that, in addition to the fetchmailrc, the msmtprc had  to be modified as well.